# Sorting Array Subscripts

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort out the grades, but subscripts will not go to their right spot. I've tried to remove `int` in each for loop, except the first one, but there was an error saying

> ‘sub’ was not declared in this scope

And the output looks like this

> Enter 15 exam grades: 90 80 70 60 50 91 81 71 61 51 92 82 72 62 52

> Students who earned an A: 3 5 9 11 14

> Students who earned a B:

> Students who earned a C:

> Students who earned a D:

> Students who earned a F: 1 2 4 6 7 8 10 12 13 15

I assume there was something wrong with the compiler, but I'm sure.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* Declaring variables */
    
    const int SIZE = 15;
    int grades[SIZE];
    
    /* Message Prompt */
    
    cout << "Enter " << SIZE << " exam grades: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    cin >> grades[SIZE];
    
    /* Results Display for A */

    cout << "Students who earned an A: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    {
        if (grades[sub] >= 90)
        {
            cout << sub + 1 << " "; 
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    /* Results Display for B */
    
    cout << "Students who earned a B: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    {
        if ((grades[sub] <= 89) && (grades[sub] >= 80))
        {
            cout << sub + 1 << " ";
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    /* Results Display for C */
    
    cout << "Students who earned a C: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    {
        if ((grades[sub] <= 79) && (grades[sub] >= 70))
        {
            cout << sub + 1 << " ";
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    /* Results Display for D */
    
    cout << "Students who earned a D: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    {
        if ((grades[sub] <= 69) && (grades[sub] >= 60))
        {
            cout << sub + 1 << " ";
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    /* Results Display for F */
    
    cout << "Students who earned a F: ";
    for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++)
    {
        if (grades[sub] <= 59)
        {
            cout << sub + 1 << " ";
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove `int`? now the compiler doesn't know what `sub` is which is why you get that error

Comment: *I assume there was something wrong with the compiler, but I'm sure* -- Hopefully you mean a bug in your code, and not the compiler.  A compiler will not have bugs for such a toy program.

Comment: It's never the compiler. Never, ever, ever. Except when it is, but seriously it is never the compiler.

Comment: I see that you just modified your code to define "int sub" in all for loops. I just test and see that your code has no compile error. It runs and completes just fine. Do you have any issue with this new code ?

Comment: I pointed out that the subscript didn't go to the correct grading display.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

`for (int sub = 0; sub < SIZE; sub++) cin >> grades[SIZE];`

It should be `grades[sub]` instead.